# Как выбрать значения из таблицы sql в виде массива?

Tags: mysql, sql

допустим есть таблица values . Я хочу в результате получить выборку в виде массива. arr=["value1", "value2"].

`select value as arr from values where parameter = 2`
Можно использовать функцию concat("[", group_concat(value, ", "), "]"). Но возможно ли обойтись без нее, и сразу выбирать данные в формате массива на уровне СУБД?

| id | parameter | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | value1 |
| 2 | 2 | value2 |
| 3 | 3 | value3 |
| 4 | 3 | value4 |
| 5 | 3 | value5 |

Comment: [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)

Comment: @Akina спасибо, как всегда выручаете! пойду раскуривать документацию.